# is there a cleaner way to debounce a method?

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

Is there a cleaner way to `_.debounce` a method using inline code? Or does it always take 3 steps?

```
@Component({
template: `
  <div (mousemove)="onChanged($event)">
  </div>
`
})
export class MyClass {

  @Output() somethingChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string]>();

  constructor(){}

  // 1. define method
  triggerChanged = ()=>{
    this.somethingChanged.emit("changed!");
  }

  // 2. debounce method
  debouncedTriggerChanged = _.debounce( this.triggerChanged, 500);

  onChanged(){
      // 3. call debounced method
      this.debouncedTriggerChanged()
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to merge 1 & 2, just turn your triggerChange method into an anonymous method inside your debounce()

Comment: dooh. why didn't I see that?

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach - leaving your suggested methods out completely:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { debounce } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    const eventStream = fromEvent(elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove')
                            .pipe(debounce(() => timer(500)));

    eventStream.subscribe(input => this.somethingChanged.emit("changed!"));
}
```

*2018-06-19: Updated to current RxJS release*